# Convert decimal into percent - VBA

Tags: vba

I'm trying to convert number in decimal format in my selection to percentages but am getting a type mismatch error.

Current code is below, where lRow is predefined integer.

```
Range("F6:F" & lRow).Select
Selection.Value = Selection.Value / 100
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0%_);(0.0%)"
```

Comment: You can not perform the division on a multi cell range (which the selection most likely is). You must do it for each cell separately, in e.g. a loop. The `NumberFormat` is ok to set on a range.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

`Selection.Value = Selection.Value / 100`

I am assuming that `Selection` typically contains more than one cell, in which case `.Value` does not return a number that can be divided but rather an array containing the value of each individual cell. Use a `For Each` loop to go through the set of cells in the selection and apply the calculation:

```
For Each cel In Selection
    cel.Value = cel.Value /100
Next
```

Also note that you don't need to select cells as if you were using Excel mouse input to do things in VBA. It is better to do something like

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("F6:F" & lRow)
```

and then use `rng` where you currently use `Selection`, for example `rng.NumberFormat = ...`

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `PasteSpecial` with `xlPasteSpecialOperationDivide`  :

```vb
With Range("F6:F" & lRow)
    With Range("F" & lRow + 1)
        .Value = 100    'put 100 to a helper cell
        .Copy           'put divider into the clipboard
    End With
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationDivide  'divide all the values by divider in the clipboard
    .NumberFormat = "0.0%_);(0.0%)"
End With
Range("F" & lRow + 1).ClearContents 'clear the helper cell
```